# How to track the open/closed status over the history of a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, api-v2, closing

I'd like to find out the times in the history of a question when it was closed and reopened.  How can I do that using API v2?

The closest relevant call I have found is [`/questions/{ids}/timeline`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-timeline), which returns a list of [`question_timeline`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question-timeline), which has a `timeline_type` field that could be `post_state_changed`.  However, there doesn't seem to be any way to find out what that state changed to: was is closed? reopened? locked? unlocked? wikified?

It seems to me that the `question_timeline` data are incomplete, and the API should be enhanced.  (Or, if there is a way to extract that information, then it should be clarified in the documentation.)

I've also looked at [`/questions/{ids}`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids), which [tells](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) you the `closed_date`.  Since there is no `reopened_date`, I conclude that `closed_date` would only be present if the question is *currently* closed, and that it doesn't tell you anything about historical state transitions.

Answer (score 2):

You can get at this information, but it's messy.

Using the `/posts/{id}/revisions` route you can query for the list of all [revision](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/revision) events for a particular question, which includes close/reopen events. These have `revision_type = "vote_based"` which you can filter the results by, but so do delete/undelete and protect/unprotect events, meaning you ultimately have to parse the `comment` field for `&lt;b&gt;Post Closed`, etc.

You can see all of the various different states in action in the [revisions of Jon Skeet Facts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#pagesize=100&ids=9134&filter=default&site=meta&run=true), which corresponds to the [on-site question history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/9134/revisions).